# Checking element is in cell above using id in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors, children

I'm having some trouble using trying to determine if a mouse click is occurring in a table cell which is directly below an element with `id=#blankElement`.

The event handlers work fine for clicking cells which are to the right or left of the specified element but if any other cells are clicked I get the 'Cell is above' alert ..

```
$(function () {
    var $tbl = $('<table border="1">').attr('id', 'grid');
    var $tbody = $('<tbody>').attr('id', 'tableBody');

    for (var i = 0; i < $("#numOfPieces").val(); i++) {

        var trow = $("<tr>"); // New row

        for (var j = 0; j < $("#numOfPieces").val(); j++) {
            $("<td>")
                    .text('Row : ' + i + ', Col: ' + j)
                    .appendTo(trow);
        }

        trow.appendTo($tbody);
    }

    $tbl.append($tbody);
    $('table').remove();
    $('body').append($tbl);
    $('#grid tr:first td:last').prev().text("");
    $('#grid tr:first td:last').prev().attr('id', 'blankElement');
});

// Event handler for clicking table cells
$('body').on('click', '#grid td', function(e) {

    if ($(this).closest('td').next("#blankElement").length){
        alert('Cell to the right');

    }else if ($(this).closest('td').prev("#blankElement").length){
        alert('Cell to the left');

    }else if ($(this).parent().next().children().eq($(this).index())){
        alert('Cell is above');
    }
});
```

Comment: some HTML and a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ ) would help greatly!

Comment: Need to see the table markup to provide an answer.

Comment: Without the markup it's a waste of time for all of us, including your's!

Comment: included code which generates table within jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, folks, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQk28/23/

There are number of things wrong with your code:

1. eq() acts like a selector and will return array of elements. when
   nothing is matched it will return [], which still evaluates to true.
2. you are selecting all children and not only the element that you are looking for (children() acts as $() - you can pass additional selectors and it will filter children for you)

Take a look at the fiddle it's pretty straight forward

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '#grid td', function(e) {

    if ($(this).closest('td').next("#blankElement").length) {
        alert('Cell to the right');

    } else if ($(this).closest('td').prev("#blankElement").length) {
        alert('Cell to the left');

    } else if ($(this).parent().next().children("#blankElement").index() == $(this).index()) {
        alert('Cell is above');
    }
});​
```